# VSTO Word Office Interop: Find References to Bookmark

Tags: ms-word, vsto, office-interop, office-addins, word-interop

Given a selection in Word which contains a `Bookmark` - e.g. a heading such as this (this is inside the `SelectionChange` event):

```
var selectionWithBookmark = e.Selection.Bookmarks.Cast<dynamic>().Select(b => b.Range as Range).FirstOrDefault();
```

How do I find all cross-references (i.e. `Type == WdFieldType.wdFieldRef`) in the document that refer to this bookmark?

I would like to find not just the `Field`s themselves, but the paragraphs containing those fields as well.

Looking for answers in either C# or VB.

I can loop/iterate all references in the document, but there is no way to link them to the Bookmark (aside from the `Code` property - but the REF number doesn't actually exist on the bookmark either from what I can see).  What it is missing is some form of `Target` property that I can compare to the bookmark itself.

Comment: I'm having a little trouble following this, a [mcve] would help, but... "the REF number doesn't actually exist on the bookmark either from what I can see". Actually, it should, but preceded by an underscore `_` so the name won't show up in the UI by default. In the Bookmarks dialog box there's a little checkbox "Hidden bookmarks": click it two, three times and a list should show up. Also `Debug.Print(bookmark.Name)` and you should see it?

Comment: Thanks Cindy, your comment around the `.Name` property made me realise that I was looking at the wrong object (`selectionWithBookmark`) - namely the containing range which doesn't have that property. With the actual `Bookmark` object it's working flawlessly! Do you want to turn this into an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following statement in the question makes me wonder...

> the REF number doesn't actually exist on the bookmark either from what
>   I can see.

The bookmark *name* should contain the REF number, but it will be preceded by an underscore _ so the name won't show up in the UI by default.

In the Bookmarks dialog box there's a little checkbox "Hidden bookmarks": click it two, three times and a list should show up, as illustrated in the following screen shot.

[image: Bookmarks dialog with REF number]

`Debug.Print(bookmark.Name)` should also show this.

Once the bookmark name is known, it shouldn't be difficult to locate the corresponding `REF` fields.